# Aligning Dynamic controls created in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
var btn1 = '<button id="btn1"  style="width: 20px" type="button">'

var btn2 = '<button id="btn2"  style="width: 20px" type="button">'
```

I have 2 buttons created dynamically. which i ll append to a DIV.

I need these buttons to be aligned in the same line.

Like

```
btn1    btn2
```

If i append  button is coming below another

```
btn1

btn2
```

But am trying to align in same line using Jquery !

How do i achieve this ?

Comment: css('display','inline-block');

Comment: what @Neil said or if it doesn't work use css('float','left')

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var btn1 = '<input id="btn1" value = "Button1" type="button">'
            var btn2 = '<input id="btn2" value = "Button2"  type="button">'
            $("#mydiv").append(btn1);
            $("#mydiv").append(btn2);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```